# Reading data from a spreadsheet and constructing matrix in python

Tags: python, csv, matrix, xls

Is there a way to make python "read" the document, exclude unnecessary elements and build an adjacency matrix of 1 and 0? I have a spreadsheet of 500 visited pages with inlinks, outlinks and dangling pages(needs to be excluded from the search).

I thought about a crude pseudocode which would look something like this:

```
for each visited page vp
 for each outlink of vp
  if link relative
   revolve link
  if ink to visited page
  write 1
  else
 if link dangling
  ignore it
 else
   write 0
```

Is it possible to somehow implement this idea within Python? Or using Matlab or R would be more useful?

Links to crawler results:
http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/sewn/ls3/sewn_2016_labsheet_3_full_crawl.txt
http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/sewn/ls3/sewn_2016_labsheet_3_full_crawl.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to make python "read" the document, exclude unnecessary elements and build an adjacency matrix of 1 and 0?

Yes

please refer to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

easiest way to start opening and reading documents:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
fileLines = f.readlines()

#do something with your lines
#properly adapt your pseudocode to
#the extracted data

f.close()
```

the rest of your questions are out of scope.